# How to apply alternating caps?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

Fast way to type or change to [*AlTeRnAtInG CaPs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_caps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitution is one way...

```
:s/\v(.)(.?)/\u\1\l\2/g
```

Breakdown:

1. `\v` : use "very magic" mode
2. `(.)` : first dot is our "odd" character; enclosed in capture group 1
3. `(.?)` : second dot is our "even" character; enclosed in capture group 2; have to make it optional in order to capitalize last char of line if it's "odd"
4. `\u` : convert to uppercase the character that follows which is...
5. `\1` : ...the "odd" character
6. `\l` : convert to lowercase the character that follows which is...
7. `\2` : ...the "even" character
8. `g` : ensure that this is repeated for every pair of characters on the line.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a macro, started on the first letter of the word (and assuming
it's all lower cast to begin with (if not do `guu` to put the line into lower
case):

```
qa~lq
```

Then just do `@a` to replay the macro (and thereafter `@@` to repeat). This
won't ensure that the first letter of each word in a sentence is of the same
case though:

```
SoMe aLtErNaTiNg tExT
```

If you need to exchange upper and lower case in some non-alternating pattern,
i.e change this:

```
SoMe wEIRd capiTaliSation Going on herE
```

to this:

```
sOmE WeirD CAPItALIsATION gOING ON HERe
```

you can do `g~~` (thanks to @Rich for the tip)

Comment: Your second example (exchanging text of line) you can do inside Vim by typing `g~~`

Comment: @Rich Thanks - I never realised there was a `g~` command

Comment: You're missing the final `q` to stop recording the macro. You need to execute it at least once (with `@a`) before you can repeat it (with `@@`). You can use a count to repeat it enough times, e.g. `999@a`. At the beginning, you might want to use `guu` to lowercase the whole line (not just the current word.)

Comment: Ah yes @filbranden you're right, thanks - I was surprised when `@@` worked for me (I thought I'd discovered a new behaviour I was previously unaware of), but I must have
been using an old recording of the same macro when I was testing it for the
answer. Updated the answer now.